# How to implement a communication between MATLAB and a separate C++ application?

Tags: c++, matlab, parallel-processing, buffer, ipc

I read that I can use TCP/IP to send data between the two applications, but I was wondering if that would be faster than using binary files and polling the files for change? I don't have time to implement both methods and benchmark, so if someone has knowledge of this I'd appreciate the input.

I would need to send two buffers back and forth, one very small (**a few KB**) and one that could be **0.1 - 1 MB** in size.

I should also mention that the C++ application runs on a cluster and is parallelized with **MPI** such that each process needs to read the entire buffer. When reading binary files, they can do it in parallel at the same time, so it's not an issue. I'm not sure if that can be done with TCP/IP.

Comment: Well, with all respect, Sir, reading files is never possible to be done in a **`[PARALLEL]`** fashion, as neither the O/S fileIO services, nor the device can read both at the BoF and EoF and any other fileSeek() location at the same time, principally. The O/S fileIO services may create a sort of false illusion of a **"just"-`[CONCURRENT]`** fileIO, but once technically inspected, it is **pure `[SERIAL]`**-schedule of a sequence of operations. The more once your initial idea has to work with a pair of files ( + add all that many other fileIO operations, that gets operated inside the O/S )

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. So would you say that it would be faster to read the file on rank 0 and then send that data to the other ranks, instead of every rank reading the files? (Assuming I ended up using file I/O for communication)

Comment: I would always say, that avoiding a fileIO is the way. Given the initial file-changes are "produced" by some process, even that process-side could **avoid paying these initial and expensive hundreds of [ms]** and may rather explicitly advertise the new data to { all | relevant }-distributed computing-agents by a non-blocking, low-latency tool, where **many orders of magnitude** -- CMP many thousands of [ms] >> tens of [us] -- **are saved**. This is also **saving the [tag:parallel-computing] edge - lesser overheads decrease devastation - as it obeys overhead-strict Amdahl's Law re-formulation**

Answer (score 0):

If you try to do this via TCP/IP you'll need to serialise the data in one application and reconstruct it in the other, using the API of your network stack. This could get messy.

One thing you could try is a memory mapped file. That's basically sharing memory between the processes. Super fast and quite common. You should just find an example for each system, c++ and MATLAB, and take it from there.

Comment: Would that work if the C++ processes are on different nodes on a cluster?

Comment: I thought you meant the processes were on the same machine. I haven't tried remote mmap, but this guy has: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1e21db42-942f-4511-a068-959116ee4f05/win32-memory-mapped-files-can-i-access-the-remote-file?forum=vcgeneral

Answer (score 0):

### Elementary, dear Watson...

**This is what a process has to pay:**

- whenever a process touches a **file** `[SERIAL]-`ly, **expect + ~12-15 [ms] access latency** on spinning drives
- whenever a process touches a file `[CONCURRENT]-`ly add **+ a few [us]** for fileIO overheads, as more than one process tries to govern when and what is intended to get read/written ( the more MPI processes try to get the hat & dictate, the lower is the probability of being an isolated access & these overheads will naturally only grow larger ) -- the more MPI-nodes try to do *( cit.)* "*polling the files for change*", the larger will overheads grow -- indeed a very bad idea for attempts to increase performance -- continuously accumulated more and more tens to hundreds to thousands [ms] are the most expensive way to go.
- whenever a process touches a **RAM** `[SERIAL]-`ly, **expect + ~80-100 [ns] access latency** on classical DDR-x DRAM. Re-reads may get masked by Cache hierarchy to cost only + few [ns]
- whenever a process touches a RAM, `[CONCURRENT]-`ly add **+ a few [ns]** as most CPUs are an out-of-order execution type hardware piece and can automatically detect and try to re-arrange a bit the memory access patterns and hide a part of this add-on latency, though at a cost of loosing some chance of Cache hits, be it due to temporal or capacity inducted collisions ( so having to pay those + ~80-100 [ns] to re-fetch from DRAM, once the Cached LRU-part got evicted.

**Next comes the cost of passing a volume of data through a limited bandwidth:**

- reading from file takes a lot of time -- for the max flow see the SATA-x,  NAS etc. specification of how many seconds it will take to move a 1 MB through. Nevertheless, expect actually a lower throughput / longer time, as not all drives have it's interface-matching performance ( interface performance does not implicate the inner parts of the device are as fast as the "cable" towards the external world - this is why this is sometimes masked by "buffered" storage on the in-drive controller's embedded cache )
- reading from memory is way faster
- reading from cache is fastest at all ( for 1MB, the whole circus may easily fit inside a localhost CPU(s) L3-cache )

### What will cause problems:

Having mentioned your code is being designed as going distributed using MPI tools, all data manipulations get a bit outside of your caching / latency masking control.

If the MPI-distributed process will try to read from some common source, be it a file or memory, all the advanced tricks may get lost theirs grounds, as a non-localhost MPI-nodes may get into issues not seen on localhost-only implementation models and MEMMAP-alike tricks get naturally out of the game.

### If performance matters the most:

may use lightweight, high-performance, asynchronous smart messaging/signalling toolkit, like ZeroMQ, ported also to MATLAB and almost all other languages ( ref. documentation ). Going this way, your design can avoid polling for changes and instead implement an explicit signal distribution of each and any relevant change to influenced peer-processing nodes, which is way smarter, yet lightweight, than trying to re-read files and will work even in LAN/(WAN)-distributed clusters **yet at the costs of not more than a few [us]** -- yes, more than thousands times less expensive than fileIO and yet capable of serving over a wide-distributed non-localhost-only computing cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not a linux expert so please correct me if I'm wrong, but looking at the installation page of ZeroMQ (and its dependencies) it appears that they need sudo priviliges, which I don't have.

Comment: Best to ask the sysadmin for a help to follow the due procedures to install the package.